# how to turn off DEP (Data Execution Prevention) without reboot?

Tags: security, internet-explorer

I'm writing a test webpage which calls into a function in a DLL file. But every time before i use IE or FF to open it i have to disable DEP(Data Execution Prevention) or the script can't be executed. Current method of disabling DEP requires reboot but i don't want to reboot.

Basically, i'm looking for a way to how to turn off DEP (Data Execution Prevention) without required reboot.

Thanks

Comment: These guys didn't answer about linux...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't disable it for a given process after it's enabled, but [SetProcessDEPPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736299.aspx) might help.

If you need to disable it for during boot, you'd have to set the `nx` boot entry with `BCDEdit /set`.

Answer (score 5):

In linux, you can use the compiler flag "-z execstack"

Answer (score 0):

[Buffer overflow exploits for windows](http://bernardodamele.blogspot.com/2009/12/dep-bypass-with-setprocessdeppolicy.html) will often call `SetProcessDEPPolicy()` after they have gained control of the instruction pointer(EIP).  This step is used to make shellcode executable.