# How to ShellCode in linux with x64 processor.

Tags: shellcode

I am working my way through [this tutorial](http://www.vividmachines.com/shellcode/shellcode.html), but it is written for 32 bit processors. I have found this note on [64 bit linux syscall](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/linuxsyscalls/). I can compile, run and objdump it.

My question is, why is the following code generated a segmentation fault.

```
/* shellcodetest.c */

char code[] = "\x48\x31\xc0\xb0\x3c\x48\x31\xff\x0f\x05";
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int (*func)();
    func = (int (*)()) code;
    (int)(*func)();
}

/*    
exitt:     file format elf64-x86-64    

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000400078 <_start>:
  400078:   48 31 c0                xor    %rax,%rax
  40007b:   b0 3c                   mov    $0x3c,%al
  40007d:   48 31 ff                xor    %rdi,%rdi
  400080:   0f 05                   syscall 
*/
```

For reference syscall 60 (\x3c) is exit(). So this should just be calling exit(0);

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to turn of DEP as suggested by @tylerl [tylerl](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/2264/tylerl) in the Information Security forum. @Adam-Miller explains how in the answer to 
[how to turn off DEP (Data Execution Prevention) without reboot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428164/how-to-turn-off-dep-data-execution-prevention-without-reboot) where he says, 'In linux, you can use the compiler flag "-z execstack"'